# ImageView not updating on change in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso, ui-thread

I have tried using Picasso and every method I could possibly find here on stackoverflow. I'm taking an image with camera and getting the value onActivity result. The imageView gets updated only after I quit and restart the application. I want imageview to change before my eyes. None of the code seems to be working.

I tried this

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                }
            });
```

nothing happens when camera view closes after hitting ok.

I also tried this:

```
   Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

but UI doesn't change, image remains the same.

I tried Async tasks, Picasso doesn't work either.

Idk how to do this, it's been a while and I'm super frustrated

Here is the code with both techniques:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {
            final Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            final File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "temp.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            uploadProfilePicToS3(destination.getAbsolutePath());

            //this doesn't work
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            thread.start();

            //not working either!
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                }
            });
```

Comment: have you tried `profile.postInvalidate()` after setting the new image?

Comment: You are already on the UI thread when `onActivityResult()` is called/returns, creating new Threads, or any Asynchronous operations and then choosing runOnUiThread will have no effect on whether the image is displayed - put some break points in as and check that onActivityResult is called..

Comment: @MarkKeen it is called because when I restart the application the changes take effect. Also, this is running from a fragment

Comment: Try to add some different filename or add currentmiliseconds to filename like temp123.jpg

Comment: you are already on mainthread, remove your thread and try.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `ImageView` is not updated is because 1) Android loads the previous image that is in the cache, as long as you’re saving the image to the same destination  2)  `onActivityResult` is called before `onResume`. This means that the image you loaded into the `ImageView` is lost when `onResume` is called.

The first problem is nicely handled by `Glide`’s `signature`, and the second problem can be handled with `onSavedInstanceState()`.

Create a `Glide signature` when you change the image. This should be different for each change e.g. current time. Then apply the `signature` as you load the image.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        final File destination = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath(), "temp.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(destination)

    //Create your signature
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss", 
        Locale.getDefault());
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    newImageSignature =  new RequestOptions()
        .signature(new ObjectKey(timeStamp));

    //Load your image
    Glide.with(yourActivity.this) // Or Fragment
        .load(bitmap) // Or Uri
        .apply(newImageSignature)
        .into(imageView);

    // You can save the uri and signature to Firebase Database, 
    // and your image to Storage here
```

Then save the new `signature` in `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (newImageSignature != null) {
        outState.putString("IMAGE_SIGNATURE”, newImageSignature.toString());
        outState.putString("IMAGE_URI”, uri.toString());
    }
}
```

Now you can retrieve the `signature` in `onCreate()`

```
Uri ImageUri;
ImageView imageView;
RequestOptions imageSignature;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retrieve your saved parameters. Or get them from a database.
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        imageSignature = new RequestOptions()
            .signature(new 
             ObjectKey(savedInstanceState.getString("IMAGE_SIGNATURE"))); 
        imageUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("IMAGE_URI"));

    // Instantiate your imageview

    // Load image
    if(imageUri != null && imageSignature != null){
        Glide.with(yourActivity.this) // Or Fragment
        .load(bitmap) // Or Uri
        .apply(newImageSignature)
        .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

NB: I just wrote this, not tested yet. Hope it gives